# How to compare string value with integer in Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

I'm getting the text as string and i need to compare it with a number, If its grater than that number then execute an `if` statement and if not then `else`.

I'm using following code :

```
string sato = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".user_reward_points")).Text;
if (sato > 1200)
{
     driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#free_points_rewards > .effect2:nth-
    child(2) .large-3:nth-child(3) > .reward_link_redeem_button_style")).Click();
}
```

Comment: Parse the String as an Integer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a software developement question.

Comment: There is nothing specific to selenium in this question.

Comment: The code does not reflect good test practice and the criteria for expected behaviour are unclear.  Please make an effort to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse string value to an integer. Try the below code:

```
String sato = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".user_reward_points")).Text;
if (Int32.Parse(sato)> 1200)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#free_points_rewards > 
   .effect2:nth-child(2) .large-3:nth-child(3) > .reward_link_redeem_button_style")).Click();
}
```